# Why does my Python program fail to read the second line of my data file?

Tags: python

I am learning python. I wanted to learn to work with text files, so I decided to make a simple console program.

The program does the following:

- Asks if you had already a profile.
- If no, then asks to create a username and a password. The information is saved in a text file.
- If yes, then asks to input your password and username.

When the user doesn't have a profile, everything works well. When the user has a profile and wants to log in, it doesn't work and I don't know why.

The username is saved in the first line of the text file and the password in the second line, so, I use readlines()[0] and readlines()[1].

The username is recognized correctly, but the password doesn't. I get this error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Archivo de prueba.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(text_file.readlines()[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
text_file = open("Archivo de prueba.txt", "r+")
    
def ask_for_account():
  global has_account
  has_account = input("Do you have an account? (Write \"Yes\" or \"No) ")
  ask_for_account()

def create_profile():
  create_user = str(input("Type your new username: "))
  create_password = str(input("Type your new password: "))
  text_file.write(create_user)
  text_file.write("\n")
  text_file.write(create_password)
    
def login():
  username = text_file.readlines()[0]
  password = text_file.readlines()[1]
  current_user = input("Type your username: ")
  current_password = input("Type your password: ")
  if str(current_user) == str(username) and str(current_password) == str(password):
    print("Succesfully logged in.")
  else:
    print("Invalid username or password")
    
if has_account == "No":
  create_profile()
elif has_account == "Yes":
  login()
else:
  print("Invalid input")
  ask_for_account()
    
text_file.close()
```

Comment: where is the ```print(text.readlines()[1])```?

Comment: I removed it because it wasn't part of the code, I just put it there while looking for a solution and forgot to erase it.

Comment: Oh sorry. I was changing things and forgot to write again the print(text.readlines()[1])  Now it is there.

Comment: Thanks, David for editing the question. Sorry for the mistakes, this is my first time in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works. I added a few comments to indicate changes.

```py
def ask_for_account():
  return input("Do you have an account? (Enter 'Yes' or 'No') ")

def create_profile():
  create_user = str(input("Type your new username: "))
  create_password = str(input("Type your new password: "))
  # Open the file for writing and close it after use.
  text_file = open("Archivo de prueba.txt", "w")
  text_file.write("{}\n".format(create_user))
  text_file.write("{}\n".format(create_password))
  text_file.close()

def login():
  # Open the file for reading and close it after use.
  text_file = open("Archivo de prueba.txt", "r")
  lines = text_file.readlines()
  text_file.close()
  # remove the newline at the end of the input lines.
  username = lines[0].rstrip()
  password = lines[1].rstrip()
  current_user = input("Type your username: ")
  current_password = input("Type your password: ")
  if current_user == username and current_password == password:
    print("Succesfully logged in.")
  else:
    print("Invalid username or password")

#
# Put program logic in one place after the methods are defined.
#
has_account = ask_for_account()
if has_account == "No":
  create_profile()
elif has_account == "Yes":
  login()
else:
  print("Invalid input")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
username = text_file.readlines()[0]
password = text_file.readlines()[1]
```

The first call to `readlines()` consumes the entire file and there are no lines remaining for the second call to read, so it returns an empty list.

Read the file *once* and save the lines in a list, then pick the desired lines from the list:

```
file_lines = text_file.readlines()
username = file_lines[0]
password = file_lines[1]
```

Also, be aware that `readlines()` puts a carriage return `\n` at the end of every line, so you might have to strip that off depending on how you use these values.

Comment: Thanks for answering. When I try to strip that off with  `strip() ` it says `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Archivo de prueba.py", line 36, in <module>
    login()
  File "Archivo de prueba.py", line 28, in login
    if str(current_user) == strip(str(username)) and str(current_password) == strip(str(password)):
NameError: name 'strip' is not defined` How do I fix that?

Comment: `strip()` is a method on string objects, not a standalone function. `username = line.strip()`